# Webpack messing up characters order causing Unexpected token error

Tags: typescript, webpack, xstate

I know that the title is not very descriptive but couldn't find better words for it. I am playing with the 'xstate' library and the build result is causing an 'Unexpected token' error.

This is my webpack.config.js:

```
var WebpackBuildNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-build-notifier');

var webpackConfig = { 
    entry: "./src/App.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist"
    },
    plugins: [
        new WebpackBuildNotifierPlugin({
          title: "Build",
          suppressSuccess: false
        })
    ],
    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",
    mode:'development',
    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" },
            { test: /\.css$/,  loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
            { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader' },
            { test: /\.(jpg|png|svg|gif|css)$/, exclude: /fabric\.css$/, loader: 'file-loader' }
        ]
    }
};


module.exports = [
    webpackConfig
];
```

After building the code the part of bundle.js looks like this which is causing the 'Unexpected token' error:

```
u
/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */}.call(this, __webpack_require__(/*! ./../../webpack/buildin/global.js */ "./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js")))ndefined
```

Xstate is being imported in this manner:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Machine, interpret } from 'xstate';

interface AppRootState{
    currentState:any
}

export class AppRoot extends React.Component<{}, AppRootState>{

    service = interpret(appRootMachine).onTransition((current)=>{
        this.setState({current});
    });

    constructor(){
        super({});
        this.state = {
            currentState:this.service.initialState
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.service.start();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
       this.service.stop();
    }
    ///Rest of the code
}
```

Comment: please provide runtime code where you importing xstate

Comment: @Ciamas did you resolve this issue ? I can't see that this was an issue with xstate or the use of it, but rather a webpack/mistype issue ?

Comment: Actually not, didn't have time for it. @TameBadger

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to eliminate all the setup variables that you might have, but here is what I tried and what worked for me when trying to replicate your issue:

I followed the instructions on the guide for typescript with React & Webpack setup [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html).

Once I reached a point where everything was working correctly, I replaced the "Hello" component content with what you provided in your question, and a "working" component ends up like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Machine, interpret } from 'xstate';

export interface AppRootProps {}
export interface AppRootState {
  currentState: any;
  current: any;
}

const appRootMachine = Machine({
  id: 'toggle',
  initial: 'inactive',
  states: {
    inactive: { on: { TOGGLE: 'active' } },
    active: { on: { TOGGLE: 'inactive' } }
  }
});

export class AppRoot extends React.Component<AppRootProps, AppRootState> {
  service = interpret(appRootMachine).onTransition((current) => {
    this.setState({ current });
  });

  constructor() {
    super({});
    this.state = {
      currentState: this.service.initialState,
      current: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.service.start();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.service.stop();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>
        Current state:
        {this.state.currentState && this.state.currentState.value}
      </h1>
    );
  }
}
```

I added the "basic" machine example from the xstate repository as your `appRootMachine` and a basic render method, trying to keep all the code as close to your implementation as possible on purpose.

I then replaced the webpack.config.js with the config you provided

- installed the dependencies required by it, `awesome-typescript-loader` & `webpack-build-notifier`
- updated the entry to `entry: "./src/index.tsx",` of `webpackConfig`
- updated the index.html line 15 to `<script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>` to use the bundle your webpack config creates

Everything worked for me after that, and I hope you find an answer in the above steps I've noted that could help you fix your project setup.

I'll also recommend the [@xstate/react package](https://github.com/davidkpiano/xstate/tree/master/packages/xstate-react) that you should consider for future use of xstate with react, and note the usage examples there, as they demonstrate better usage than what is shown here to resolve your issue.